# An instance of EventSource with Guid 74af9f20-af6a-5582-9382-f21f674fb271 already exists

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

This trace message is popping up all over our AppInsights instance. I don't know what is means, or what could be the cause. I'm happy to provide any details that can help debug.

Trace message

> AI (Internal): ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Core: An instance of EventSource with Guid 74af9f20-af6a-5582-9382-f21f674fb271 already exists.

sdkVersion : dotnet:2.7.2-23439

Code Sample :

```
        [FunctionName("UpdateFunction")]
    public async static Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("Product-events", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")]Message[] objMessage,
        [Blob("%ProductBlobContainerName%", System.IO.FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer productblobContainer,
        [CosmosDB(databaseName: "DatabaseName", collectionName: "procudtCollectionName", ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnectionString")]DocumentClient client,
        ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        TelemetryClient telemetry = TelemetryCreation.Instantiate(context);
        ConcurrentBag<int> DocumentToInsert= new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        ConcurrentBag<Message> DocumentToBeDeleted = new ConcurrentBag<Message>();
        try
        {
            telemetry.TrackTrace($"{context.FunctionName} Started", SeverityLevel.Information, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {
                    "PrefixName",
                    objMessage[0].ToString()
                },
                {
                    "NumberOfMsgs",
                    objMessage.Length.ToString()
                }
            });

            await UpsertProvider(objMessage, productblobContainer, client, telemetry, DocumentToInsert, DocumentToBeDeleted);
            if (DocumentToBeDeleted.Count > 0)
            {
                DeleteProviders.DeleteProvider(DocumentToBeDeleted.ToArray(), client, context, telemetry);
            }

            telemetry.TrackTrace($"{context.FunctionName} Completed", SeverityLevel.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            telemetry.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "Azure Background Function Name",context.FunctionName },
                { "Read Data from container > folder",  productblobContainer.ToString() + ">" + objMessage[0].PrefixName.ToString()},
                { "Total Documents received", objMessage.Length.ToString() },
                { "Number of documents to insert", DocumentToInsert.Count.ToString() },
                 { "List of Documents to be updated", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentToInsert).ToString() },
                { "Number of documents skipped (Location is null)", DocumentToBeDeleted.Count.ToString() },
                { "List of Documents skipped", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentToBeDeleted).ToString() },
                { "Exception Message",ex.Message },
                { "Exception InnerMessage",ex.InnerException.ToString() }
                });

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet, where you are getting this error

Comment: Can you provide more information about your scenario and your function's setup? Are you performing logging operations within your Function or using a custom logger?

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT shared a code, Please look once and provide a solution if any.

Comment: @KatyShimizu shared a code, Please look once and provide a solution if any.

Comment: What is the version of application insight. is it lower or equal than 2.7.2? If not can you try to down grade and see. Also make sure your function doesn't have both the version. Check this thread : https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/973

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT  “Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.8.1“ currently. trying to remove package or downgrade it.