# Azure Function ~3 - AI (Internal): ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Azure-Core

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger, azure-form-recognizer

My project (.net core) includes an **Azure Function (~3)** as well a Azure Storage Account (Blobs). Currently, when processing my blobs from Storage Account via the **Azure Form Recognizer API**, I get the following error via Application Insights:

```
AI (Internal): [Azure-Core] ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Azure-Core: An instance of EventSource with Guid 44cbc7c6-6776-5f3c-36c1-75cd3ef19ea9 already exists.
```

If the function runs locally in my development environment (Visual Studio 2019) everything works without problems, via my local.settings.json I already use the same Azure Form Recognizer API as well as the same Azure Storage Account. Therefore, only the operation of my Function runtime differs. Once locally via Visual Studio and once deplyoed to my Azure Function (~3).

I use the following configuration of my packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.FormRecognizer" Version="3.1.0-beta.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.18.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
```

My Azure Function (~3) sample:

```
        public static async Task RunAsync(
        [TimerTrigger("0 00 08 * * 1-5")] TimerInfo myTimer,         
        [Blob("%IncomingContainer%", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "myStorageAccountString")]
        CloudBlobContainer incomingContainer,
        [Blob("%AnalysedContainer%", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "myStorageAccountString")]
        CloudBlobContainer analysedContainer,                        
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // do stuff via Azure Form Recognizer API
    }
```

Does anyone have the same experience? In the past there was this problem, here the workaround could help to delete the existing Azure Function and to deploy it again. [Similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400882/an-instance-of-eventsource-with-guid-74af9f20-af6a-5582-9382-f21f674fb271-alread) could not help me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [RohitRanjanMS](https://github.com/RohitRanjanMS). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

`Azure.Storage.Blobs` and `Azure.Identity` internally depends on `Azure.Core`. You need to update `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and `Azure.Identity` with **the latest version**.

You can refer to [AI (Internal): [Azure-Core] ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Azure-Core: An instance of EventSource with Guid xxx already exists](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7393#issuecomment-930820069)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you